# Where adding pessimistic lock in using hasMany?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, pessimistic-locking

Suppose I have this code

**Domain**

```
class Parent{
   static hasMany =  [Childs:Child]
}


class Child {
   String name
}
```

**Controller**

```
def ParentInstance = Parent.get(1) //Parent.lock(1)

ParentInstance.Childs.each {
    //it.lock()
    it.name = "titi"
}

ParentInstance.save()
```

The lock should be added for each child instance or just adding it when getting the parent?

Comment: What lock? There is no locking in above code snippet.

Comment: I added lock on comments